# CSS div position for magazine-like theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap 3 for the CSS framework. Basically I have 2 rows with 3 columns of articles.

## Option 1

first approach which is using below code (skeleton), Im able to follow exactly like sample design (div in column will position to below) but if Im using this approach, is hard to integrate with backend.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Option 2:

So, i try using this approach, but Im unable to remove the gap between 2 div. Please help

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="post">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: have you considered using something like http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at plugins like [Wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) or [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)